# Can't get request a link with Axios due to No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

I am trying to use the cryptocompare api to get a list of coindata with axios but I can't figure out how to get around this issue I believe it's a CORS issue, but I am not sure.

The full error is as follows:
Failed to load https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 524.

I am using axios with the following code:

```
addCoinData(coinData) {
  axios.get('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/')
  .then(res => {
    const crypto = res.data;
    this.setState({crypto: crypto});
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  console.log(this.state.crypto);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their API just changed the url for the data that you want to get.

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist

I've successfully made a GET request test with this url with axios as well.

```
axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
})
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked the URL was working with postman so I thought it would be fine to use with axios