# Cannot get data from data from end point due to the cors policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the same problem as this guy. '[Can't get request a link with Axios due to No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991663/cant-get-request-a-link-with-axios-due-to-no-access-control-allow-origin-head)' . 
        But it's weird that i can get data from this endpoint by Postman and even from another project.

```
    axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist') 
         .then(res => { // data
            console.log(res.data) //console
            })
   .catch(function (error) { //errors
         console.log(error);
         });     
const setAuthToken = token => {
    if(token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    } else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
    }
};
```

Maybe there is some workaround. I am using node js as backend but only for register and login users, i don't think that this can have some impact. But i am making the token request using headers, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: what have you tried? what errors are you getting?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does your server look like? Are you using express?

Comment: I an using express, but this endpoint has nothing to do with my backend. I think the problem is that i use headers in my token request
const setAuthToken = token => {
    if(token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    } else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. I only need to clear headers via delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] before my request